# Not being able to write a query that retrieves values between certain dates

Tags: oracle, toad

```
SELECT * from my_table where product_number = '86354' and period_v in ('1/1/2019','1/31/2019');
```

What i also tried:

```
SELECT * from my_table where product_number = '86354' and period_v between '1/1/2019' and '1/31/2019'

SELECT * from my_table where product_number = '86354' and period_v between #1/1/2019#, #1/31/2019#

SELECT * from my_table where product_number = '86354' and period_v between 1/1/2019 and  31/1/2019
```

my dates in the sql database have the following format:

```
2/20/2019
```

month/day/year

Comment: What type are these dates stored as? And what [tag:rdbms] are you using? [tag:oracle] and [tag:mysql] are two different RDBMSs...

Comment: stored in oracle

Comment: And what about the datatypes? Are these `varchar`s or `date`s?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend in Oracle:

```
select t.*
from my_table t
where t.product_number = 86354 and 
      period_v >= date '2019-01-01' and
      period_v < date '2019-02-01';
```

If you are storing *strings* that **you** are interpreting as dates, then you should fix your data model.  Oracle -- as with almost all other databases -- has a type just to store dates, conveniently called `date`.  You can convert the values on the fly:

```
      to_date(period_v, 'DD/MM/YYYY') >= date '2019-01-01' and
      to_date(period_v, 'DD/MM/YYYY') < date '2019-02-01';
```

Although this can be done, I strongly recommend that you use the correct data type.

In MySQL, you would remove the date keyword:

```
select t.*
from my_table t
where t.product_number = 86354 and 
      period_v >= '2019-01-01' and
      period_v < '2019-02-01';
```

Note that I removed the single quotes around `86354`.  Presumably this is a number.  It is best not to mix types.

Also, the comparison uses `>=` and `<`.  That is on purpose  The above code works for both dates and dates with time components.